# Сортировка двухмерного динамического массива строк в алфавитном порядке СИ

Tags: c, массивы, строки, сортировка, динамические-массивы

Пытаюсь отсортировать массив в алфавитном порядке. Массив будет состоять из имени и фамилии. Пробовал заполнять массив с помощью **gets()** , была проблема с выводом строк. Потом решил попробовать считать **scanf()-ом**, тут столкнулся c проблемкой, что это две отдельные строки, и как их отсортировать, даже представить не могу. Можно ли как-то привязать первую строку ко второй, или объединить их в одну? Или какой-то особый метод сортировки подскажите. 
Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#define size 50

struct student {
    char meno1[size];
    char meno2[size];
};

int main() {
    struct student natural;
    struct student perepis[size];
    int cislo;
    int check = 0;
    scanf("%d", &cislo);
    getchar();
    while (1) {
        int n;
        n = scanf("%s %s", perepis[check].meno1[check], perepis[check].meno2[check]);
        if (n == EOF) break;
        check++;
    }
    int w;
    char* minimum;
    for (int a = 0; a < check; a++) {
        minimum = perepis[a].meno1;
        w = a;
        for (int b = a + 1; b < check; b++) {
            if (strcmp(minimum, perepis[b].meno1) > 0) {
                minimum = perepis[a].meno1;
                w = b;
            }
        }
        natural = perepis[a];
        perepis[a] = perepis[w];
        perepis[w] = natural;
    }
    puts("Prijati studenti:");
    for (int g = 0; g < check; g++) {
        printf("%s %s\n", perepis[g].meno1[g], perepis[g].meno2[g]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста, всем заранее спасибо! :)

Comment: Предлагаю сделать структуру состоящую из полей 'фамилия' и 'имя' (ну, если массивы внутри структуры хочется динамические, то еще надо будет добавить поля для размеров этих массивов). А потом делать массив таких структур. Ну и сортировать тогда можно будет по двум полям: сначала по фамилии, а если фамилии совпадут, то и по имени. Как-то так. И если будете хранить кириллицу, то не забывайте про локализацию, иначе, с большой вероятностью, с сортировкой получите сюрприз ;-).

Comment: @Vladimir Я попробовал сделать как вы сказали, но пока только сортировку по первому слову что вводится(у меня все латиницей). вышло вот так: (я поменял условие вопроса). Выдает Segmentation fault

Comment: Так а теперь в чем проблема? С чем помогать? И это теперь не двумерный массив (это к заголовку вопроса), т.к. в структуру можно и возраст потом добавить или еще чего полезного. И вообще, по местным правилам лучше не менять вопрос, а сформулировать новый. Да, сейчас эти "две строки" и есть связанные - это же одна структура.

Comment: У Вас тут полно мелких косяков + сортировка сделана неверно (обмен значениями надо делать внутри условного оператора, а не вне внутреннего цикла). Первый косяк с вводом: что означает эта строка? `n = scanf("%s %s", perepis[check].meno1[check], perepis[check].meno2[check]);`. Зачем там стоит [check] у строк внутри структуры? Вы хотите одному символу присвоить строку? Скорее, это и есть причина сегфолта. Разбейте программу на части (ввод, сортировка, вывод) и отлаживайте их по очереди. С выводом у Вас такая же проблема (разве, может без сегфолта обойдется).

Comment: И для сортировки: сделайте две отдельных функции - одну для обмена значений (обычно зовется `swap()`), другую для сравнения структур (и обзовите например, `cmp()` - возвращаемое значение можете взять как у `strcmp()`). Тогда программа станет гораздо проще в понимании (как оно работает и в каком месте косячит).

Comment: @Vladimir Я исправил косяк с сегфолтом, спасибо, а можете конкретнее подсказать в чем ошибка сортировки?

Comment: Я глубоко не пытался вникнуть, каким алгоритмом сортировки Вы пользуетесь, поэтому ошибка может есть, а может нет. Для классической пузырьковой обмен значениями массива, вроде как, полагается сразу же в условном операторе, как только сравнили пару значений. Но тогда и про минимум не надо заботиться (а Вы минимум по массиву ищете...) В общем, если все работает и если в алгоритме так и было задумано, то значит ошибки нет :-). Это если бы были явные отсылки к конкретному типу сортировки, тогда надо смотреть внимательнее.